# Error while converting CER to CRT using openssl

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have openssl installed, and my goal is to convert my CER file to .CRT for an SSL update requirement. I keep running into the error (pasted below)

The code I am using in the console is:

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in Downloads\certificate.cer -out certificate.crt
```

Error:
C220000:error:80000002:system library:file_open:No such file or directory:providers\implementations\storemgmt\file_store.c:269:calling stat( Downloads\certificate.cer)
AC220000:error:16000069:STORE routines:ossl_store_get0_loader_int:unregistered scheme:crypto\store\store_register.c:237:scheme= C
AC220000:error:1608010C:STORE routines:inner_loader_fetch:unsupported:crypto\store\store_meth.c:359:No store loader found. For standard store loaders you need at least one of the default or base providers available. Did you forget to load them? Info: Global default library context, Scheme ( C : 0), Properties ()
Unable to load certificate

Comment: The error messages says that the given input file does not exist. Apart from that it is not clear what you are trying to do: CER and CRT are not actual file formats but only file extensions. The formats are PEM and DER. And right now you are trying to convert from PEM (explicitly given with `-inform PEM`) to PEM (which is the default output format) - which just does not make sense since input and output format are the same.

Comment: i have same issue on MacOS but on linux it works